# Count logical values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column with 5 logical values: 3 trues and 2 falses. I want to count the number of trues in B4:B8 and output it in B10. How can I do this:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: I suggest you look into the COUNTIF() formula.

Comment: You can use `COUNTIF(B4:B8,TRUE)` to count TRUE and and for FALSE 'COUNTIF(B4:B8,FALSE)` ☺

Answer (score 1):

Use for B10 the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B4:B8,TRUE)
```

If the columns are text, use:

```
=COUNTIF(B4:B8,'TRUE')
```

See the [COUNTIF function](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/countif.html).

Answer (score 0):

If values are actually logical then use:

```
=COUNTIF(B4:B8 ,TRUE)
```

`COUNTIF` if allows you to choose  a range, and a criteria, and counts how many times that criteria is met with the range.

```
=COUNTIF( range , criteria )
```